# Why some Graphics cannot be captured by MathLink in NETLink?

Tags: graphics, notebooks, mathlink-or-wstp, .netlink

I'm trying test on calling mathematica function from .NET application by running demo application *MathKernelApp.exe* which could be located at

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Links\NETLink\Examples\Part2\MathKernelApp\bin\Release
```

when a simple code invoked

```
Plot[Sin[x],{x,-4,4}]
```

the graphics shown immediately, found below, but this code is invoked not.

```
ListPlot[Range[100]]
```

[image]
and this code works in Notebook but not in the demo .net app.

```
CurrentImage[]
```

If the picture or image of  `CurrentImage[]` could be caputured, how the result(s) of `CurrentImage[]//Dynamic` shall be acquired in this case?

I've tried to modify some Properties of MathLink and  re-compile the .net project, it still not work. but the upper codes' results  executed in notebook seems the same form,  is there any thing should be improved with the .NETLink?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the problem of the demo .net project. some lines' codes should be modified properlly to enable the kernel sending result.

```
mathKernel.ResultFormat = Wolfram.NETLink.MathKernel.ResultFormatType.TraditionalForm;
```

and

```
//resultBox.Text = (string)mathKernel.Result;
this.graphicsBox.Image = (Image)mathKernel.Result;
```

Then re-compile the demo project and run it.The MathLink source for NETLink .net side should be read through to make best use of it.

```
C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\11.2\SystemFiles\Links\NETLink\Source
```

The code `CurrentImage[]` works too, but `CurrentImage[]//Dynamic` not.